# Как установить динамически изменяющийся атрибут action для формы

Tags: jquery, javascript

У меня есть форма:

```
<form id="form_filter" action="./shop/category/" method="get">
```

В ней список категорий:

```
<select name="categ" id="categs">
<option value="cd">CD</option>
<option value="dvd">DVD</option>
<option value="books">Книги</option>
<option value="other">Прочее</option>
</select>
```

Мне нужно чтобы по событию onChange для categ менялся action для формы.

Сейчас код такой:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var act = $('form#form_field').attr('action')+$('#categs').val();
    $('#categs').change(function() {
        $('form#form_filter').attr('action',act);
        alert($('form#form_filter').attr('action'));
    });
});
</script>
```

Но увы action остаётся тот что был сначала на странице и никак не хочет меняться. Как быть?

Comment: А не лучше ли проверять единственным обработчиком какой выбран пункт и выполнять необходимые действия?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function chAction(input) {
  var f = document.getElementById('form_filter');
  if (!f) return false;
  f.action = './shop/category/'+input.value;
  }
</script>
<select name="categ" id="categs" onchange="chAction(this)">
...
</select>
```

Comment: Отличный вариант. Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Вот тут:

```
var act = $('form#form_field').attr('action')+$('#categs').val();
```

Точно должно быть:

```
form#form_field
```

?Это же не эта форма.
У меня все работает.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var initial_action = $('form#form_filter').attr('action');
    $('#categs').change(function() {
        alert($('#categs').val());
        var act = initial_action + $('#categs').val();
        $('form#form_filter').attr('action',act);
        alert($('form#form_filter').attr('action'));
    });
});
```

Проблемы было две.
1) вы записывали в act в самом начале, а потом его **не меняли** по событию onchange.
2) вы обращались к несуществующей форме. См. выше
3) Мне стыдно

Comment: + после двух изменений экшн стал бы "./shop/category/cddvd"

Comment: Точняк. Поправил

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    puti = $('#form_filter').attr('action');
    $('#categs').change(function () {
        var act = puti + $('#categs').val();
        $('#form_filter').attr('action', act);
        alert($('#form_filter').attr('action'));
    });
});
</script>
```