# Ссылка со значением из инпута

Tags: html, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток.

`Страница_1`, инпут (name='search'), рядом охота сделать 3 кнопки, на `страницу_2`, которая будет искать, введенное в 'инпут'. Кнопки 3, т.к. искать надо будет в разных местах, и не могу понять, как значение из 'инпута' добавить в ссылку, т.к. ссылка загружается уже готовой, а значение в 'инпут' вводят.

Подскажите, как такое организовать?

p.s. ссылки пока в не рабочем виде такие:

```
<a href="mypage.php?v=1&s=значение_инпута">
<a href="mypage.php?v=2&s=значение_инпута">
<a href="mypage.php?v=3&s=значение_инпута">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("input#myinputId").change(function(){//Обработка события изменения. Надо подключить jquery
  var inputvalue = $(this).val();//Читаем значение инпута
  $("a.mychanginglink").each(function(index){// берем все ссылки, которые нужно поправить и пробегаемся по ним
    $(this).attr('href','mypage.php?v='+index+'&s='+inputvalue);//изменяем у каждой аттрибут href, согласно шаблону, описанному в задаче
  });
});
```

нативный JS:

```
<script>
function editLinks(searchvalue){
    var anc = new Array();
    for(var index=1; index<=3; index++){
        anc[index] = document.getElementById('href'+index);
        anc[index].href = "mypage.php?v="+index+"&s="+searchvalue;
    }
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<input onchange="editLinks(this.value)" name="search" />
<!--<input onkeyup="editLinks(this.value)" name="search" /> - onkeyup для мгновенного измененя. onchange - при снятии фокуса-->
<a href="#" id="href1">go1</a>
<a href="#" id="href2">go2</a>
<a href="#" id="href3">go3</a>
```

нативный JS для других форм и инпутов:

```
<script>
function editInputs(searchvalue){
    var inp = new Array();
    for(var index=1; index<=3; index++){
        inp[index] = document.getElementById('inp'+index);
        inp[index].value = searchvalue;
    }
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<input onchange="editInputs(this.value)" name="search" />
<!--<input onkeyup="editInputs(this.value)" name="search" /> - onkeyup для мгновенного измененя. onchange - при снятии фокуса-->

<form action='mypage.php'>
<input type='hidden' value="1" name="v" />
<input type='hidden' value="" id="inp1" name="s" />
<button type='submit'>go1</button>
</form>
<form action='mypage.php'>
<input type='hidden' value="2" name="v" />
<input type='hidden' value="" id="inp2" name="s" />
<button type='submit'>go2</button>
</form>
<form action='mypage.php'>
<input type='hidden' value="3" name="v" />
<input type='hidden' value="" id="inp3" name="s" />
<button type='submit'>go3</button>
</form>
```

Еще полезно почитать вот это: [Как установить динамически изменяющийся атрибут action для формы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/28836/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82-action-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B)

Comment: Добавил комментарии.

Comment: Прописал именно так. Не сработала ни одна из ссылок. Просто переход на mypage.php# (добавляется только решетка). А можно узнать, тупой до жути вариант: как сделать 3 формы, с 1 инпутом в каждом (type="hidden"), который будет автоматически равен заполняемому мной, первому инпуту?

Comment: Ну вот вам на нативном JS. В чем проблема? =)

Comment: Я попробовал, не сработало. (А если бы код работал, он мне понравился бы.)

Comment: Ах, да. Если хотите, чтобы менялось в реальном времени, а не при снятии фокуса, замените onchange на onkeyup

Comment: ура! теперь все получилось! на последок, хотелось бы знать альтернативу этому методу: как при заполнении инпута (который не принадлежит ни к одной из форм), автоматически заполнить инпуты (3шт) в других формах, и сделать их скрытыми (type="hidden")?

Comment: Ну, как-то так. См обновленную версию.

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте форму, введите значение, скопируйте ссылки, и будет у вас 4 кнопки. Кодировка страницы какая?.. Текст на русском?

Comment: Кодировка 1251, текст на русском. Скопировать откуда куда? Поподробнее можно? Может тогда 3 формы, со скрытыми инпутами, которые будут как-то равны видимому инпуту, и тогда это как вариант.

Comment: Я так понимаю, вам нужно что-то типа 
`<a href="mypage.php?v=1&s=%D0%B7%D0%BD...">значение_инпута</a>`. В поисковики напишите ключ, и скопируйте адрес, самый простой способ - вот ссылка `mypage.php?v=1&s=%D0%B7%D0%...` Еще учтите, что в урл вы получаете значение в utf-8, нужно следить за этим, если свой пхп.

Comment: Господа, давайте остановимся на том, как при заполнении инпута (который не принадлежит ни к одной из форм), автоматически заполнить инпуты (3шт) в других формах, и сделать их скрытыми, остальное будет не сложно.

Comment: так же, только вместо ссылок и хрефов - инпуты и значения:
inp[index].value = "searchvalue";

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type='text' name='s1'>

<form action="mypage.php?v=1" method="post" name="form">
<input type='text' name='v1' onKeyUp="var i1 = document.getElementById('v1'); var i2 = document.getElementById('s1'); i1.onkeyup = function(){ i1.value = i2.value;}">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="кнопка1">

<form action="mypage.php?v=2" method="post" name="form">
<input type='text' name='v2' onKeyUp="var i3 = document.getElementById('v2'); var i4 = document.getElementById('s1'); i3.onkeyup = function(){ i3.value = i4.value;}">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="кнопка2">

<form action="mypage.php?v=3" method="post" name="form">
<input type='text' name='v3' onKeyUp="var i5 = document.getElementById('v3'); var i6 = document.getElementById('s1'); i5.onkeyup = function(){ i5.value = i6.value;}">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="кнопка3">
```

я имею в виду, что то в роде этой конструкции. она не рабочая, сейчас я в ней ищу косяки. если кто подскажет буду рад. с помощью этого можно без jquery, JS

Comment: Ну, как-то так. Раскопируйте только аккуратно:

    <input type='text' name='s1' id='s1'>
    
    <form action="mypage.php?v=1" method="post" name="form">
    <input type='text' name='v1' id='v1' onKeyUp="var i1 = document.getElementById('v1'); var i2 = document.getElementById('s1'); i1.value = i2.value; ">
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="кнопка1">

А так - почти все верно. Но смысл этой конструкции для меня загадка. =))))))

Comment: эм... уже пробовал вписывать id, даже в этом виде конструкция не работает

Comment: пруфлинк. У меня все работает прекрасно: когда пытаемся изменить инпуты с именем v1,v2... нам настойчиво возвращают им значение s1

Comment: у меня если установить курсор в " name='v1' id='v1' " и нажать стереть - тоже значение становиться от " name='s1' id='s1' " , только вот почему не сразу - не пойму.

Comment: не сразу, потому что у вас написано onkeyUP. Было бы onkeyPRESS было бы сразу, но тут же бы затиралось(если стираете) или дописывалось бы(если пишете)

Comment: Если хотите, чтобы при установке фокуса - надо вообще onclick